# Foreign Key in web forms

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am creating web forms for users to enter data into my database. Now I am thinking of a good way to enter/choose foreign keys. For example I have a table A which has 1:n relation to table B. I want to create a  form for table b. The user can enter the normal information in input boxes. To enter the foreign key I thought about a dropdown list, where all entries of table A are displayed. Unfortuanately, the dropdown list of HTML can only display one coulmn. So I cannot display the ID and the name of the picked entry.

Does someone know a smart way to display the name of the entry but pass the id?

Now I am doing something like this. But here only the id of the picked entry is displayed for the user. I want to display the name, but pass the id.

```
<select name="input_modul">
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT id, Name FROM tableA;";

if($result = $con->query($sql)) {
    $rows = $result->num_rows;
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {                                    
        echo "<option>". $row['id'] . "</option>";
    }                   
}
?> </select>
```

Comment: Erm... `echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['Name']}</option>";`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply pass `$row['id']` to the `value`-attriubute of the `option`-element

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
```

This way, the value of `$row['name']` will be the displayed value in the list, while `$row['id']` will be passed along to do stuff with (get / post / others)